# Merge multiple row subquery into corelated SQL query

Tags: sql, join, correlated-subquery

I have a correlated SQL sub query which returns multiple rows. For instance,

```
SELECT NAME AS NAME1,
(SELECT NAME FROM ...) AS NAME2 /*this inner select returns more than one rows*/ 
FROM PERSONAL_INFORMATION
```

Is it possible to merge the rows returned by NAME2 with rest of the main query, here `NAME1`, that is. 
What I am thinking is kind of a cross product shown below where I can group all the given instances using `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT`?

```
NAME1_1  NAME2_1
NAME1_1  NAME2_2
NAME1_2  NAME2_1
NAME1_2  NAME2_2
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Please share table structure and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `CROSS JOIN` then.

```
SELECT I1.NAME AS NAME1, I2.NAME AS NAME2 
FROM PERSONAL_INFORMATION I1
CROSS JOIN PERSONAL_INFORMATION2 I2;
```

If you need more detail, you may use `GROUP BY` :

```
SELECT I1.NAME AS NAME1, I2.NAME AS NAME2, 
       COUNT(1) cnt, SUM(COL2) sum_col1 ...
FROM PERSONAL_INFORMATION I1
CROSS JOIN PERSONAL_INFORMATION2 I2
GROUP BY I1.NAME, I2.NAME;
```